# merging 2 html files into a single vm (velocity macro)

Tags: html, velocity

I have two html files, I used 2 different frameworks to create 2 different web application for smart phones and other devices such as tablets.

now I have to use Velocity Macro, and merge this two html files into a single vm, that generates 2 outputs depending on a configuration.

i have been searching for methods to do this and I found this: http://www.roseindia.net/apachevelocity/macro-wrap-html.shtml

My question is do I need to build a Java fie just like in the link and then make a vm file, or can I just make a single vm file without making any java files?

if my question in unclear let me know I try to explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java class shown there is just to demonstrate the template, and all the template does is demonstrate how to use the Velocity `#macro` directive.

IMO putting both HTML files into a single VM template is a bad idea, because it will be large and difficult to understand, modify, and debug. Instead, consider using the [`#parse`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Parse) or [`#include`](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Include) directives.

Alternatively, consider a mechanism at a higher level to serve the appropriate pages directly instead of pushing the template decision-making process into the templates themselves--this is arguably the best solution.